# implement departments for org1 in hyperledger fabric 2.2

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a network of 5 organizations, one of which consists of 2 departments.
I tried to search for something on the internet but couldn't find anything.
example scenario:
-org1 department
-org1 deparment2
-org2, org3,org4 and org 5.
Could someone explain to me how the departments (organization units) in hyperledger fabric work and how they can be implemented in practice.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

To implement this process, you have to use Hyperledger Fabric CA to generate your crypto material.

Hyperledger Fabric CA docs: https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/

You can easily implement organizational department by adding affiliation. You can find your question specific answer in the following link:
https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#adding-an-affiliation

Comment: thank you very much for the reply.
I suspected it couldn't be done using cryptogen to generate certificates, now I have confirmation :)
I'm going to read the documentation you sent me.